# React Component Submit form function not getting values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form component which I submit and then want to pass the data to a function after submit but I get a blank alert message.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SubmitForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {title: ''};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.getdata(this.state.title, this.state.firstname, this.state.lastname);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  getdata(title) {
    alert(title);
    alert(firstname);
    alert(lastname);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>

              <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
              <input type="text" id="title" />

              <label htmlFor="firstname">Firstname</label>
              <input type="text" id="firstname" />

              <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
              <textarea id="lastname"  rows="3"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SubmitForm;
```

How can I fix this so I get the data?

Comment: you're not passing enough params in `getdata`

Comment: A few comments. One, you don't need to use `this.handleSubmit.bind(this)` on your `<form>` element. You are already binding the correct context of `this` in your constructor. So just `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` will work just fine.

Comment: As @DanielLizik said the params for your `getdata` function is only listing 1 Yet, you are trying to use 3. You need to either add to the argument list or remove the calls to `firstname` and `lastname` in that function.

Comment: You are only storing `title` in the state. You will need to add `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: You should pass props to your `super` function. Something like `constructor(props) { super(props); .......... }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your form input elements do not have value attribute which are set to state. In React, you should use 'Controlled Components' on forms.

See the related React documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Each one of your components will need to have a handler for the `onChange` event.

```
function handleTitleChange(event) {
  this.setState(function() {
    return { title: event.target.value };
  });
}

<input type="text" id="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange.bind(this)} />
```

Here is a link to the React documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

There are also uncontrolled components but this isn't the "recommended" way.

Answer (score 0):

These are the problems with your code:

1. You are binding `handleSubmit` twice.

   - On the constructor `this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);`
   - and on the form prop onSubmit `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>`
2. You aren't handling the input values on your form. You should do something to access the value entered on each input, listening for an `onChange` event ([Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)) or accessing it as a [Uncontrolled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)
3. Your `getdata()` method is wrong, you are setting one parameter and passing three arguments.

Your definition is:

```
  getdata(title) {
    alert(title);
    alert(firstname);
    alert(lastname);
  }
```

And you are calling it like:

```
this.getdata(this.state.title, this.state.firstname, this.state.lastname);
```

That's not how functions work. To make it work with as above you'd need to define it like:

```
getdata(title, firstName, lastName) {
  alert(title);
  alert(firstName);
  alert(lastName);
}
```

So once you fix all those errors you should take a look at the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html) to learn more about how React works.

Meanwhile here is a workable example with uncontrolled components from the React documentation that will help you understand how to make your example work:

```js
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.input.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" ref={(input) => this.input = input} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

 <div id="app"></div>
```